# Netflix Questions

Tags: discussion, closing

There seems to be a few (not a lot, but a few) questions about Netflix and how it relates to various video game systems.

I understand that Netflix is not a video game, and therefore I understand why my question would have been closed as it is not related directly to a video game; I just would like to know, if not here, where should I ask my PS3 Netflix related questions?

For reference, my original question: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/114217/accessing-other-countries-netflix

Comment: I want to say [Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com) but I'm not sure it would be on topic there either...

Comment: SuperUser is probably the safest bet.

Comment: Yeah, I'm all over Movies & TV right now (a question about Community sparked this whole thought process), but they don't have a space for it there either.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, I know this probably isn't the usual question you guys get on here.

Comment: I'd want to say SuperUser although it would likely involve VPNs or proxies, something not really suited to streaming videos.

Comment: There's also the legality of doing this.  We here don't take a kind view of anything resembling piracy, but I'm not sure how strict they are at SuperUser.

Comment: And I completely understand and approve of that. My situation has me travel to and from Canada frequently, so I don't think it would fall under the banner of illegality.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just to be clear: using the Netflix app for PS3 is on-topic. Doing the necessary network magicks to bypass geographical restrictions isn't. I suggest searching on Super User for that.

Comment: What if the magicks require Mana?

Comment: @jmfsg Then you'll have to ask him yourself.

Comment: Ha-Ha-Ha! Ha-Ha!

Comment: @jmfsg Luckily I think I've got a Plains around here somewhere I can tap.